# How to cutout and keep only the contents of a circle of vectors with Inkscape?

Tags: inkscape, crop

I have a document of 75+ vector graphics laid out in a grid fashion that fills the entire page.

I would like to create a "circular crop" of the grid, leaving only the vector objects and portions that are within the circle, and erasing anything outside of the circle.  Just like in baking cookies....cut the cookie, and get rid of the surrounding cookie dough.

How can I do that with Inkscape, and assuming I can, how does one correctly refer to this for further googling and research?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're right about terminology. The term you seek is "mask." When I searched "Inkscape mask," one of the better results is in the [Inkscape manual site](https://inkscape-manuals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/clipping-and-masking.html).

[image: clip area]

[image: after clip]

Above images from linked site.